# Find the eigenvector with maximum overlap

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Given a large symmetric matrix $A$, there are methods to find the largest or smaller eigenvalue, or the eigenvalue closest to some initial value.

Is there any method to find the normalized eigenvector with maximum overlap (dot product) with an initial vector?

Comment: The question doesn't quite make sense. If $v$ is an eigenvector, then so are $2v$ and $3v$ and $10000000000000000000000v$ and so on, so the dot product with the initial vector is unbounded; there is no maximum.

Comment: @GerryMyerson one could consider normalised eigenvectors, obviously.

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something, I fixed the question.

Comment: Please see https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28111/eigenvector-with-maximum-overlap/30528#30528 for the solution!